# Exception Handling Workaround in C#

Tags: c#, exception

I was trying to parse some strings. Since I'm new to C# I was curious at some point you can see below.

When the `Lines_Array[i]` is empty(`Lines_Array[i].Length==0`) it throws an exception. Which is already what I want in Example #2 and useless in Example #1.

**I want to get rid of Exception. Because zero-length string will be my limit.** Is there any solution, alternative or workaround to this?

Example #1:

```
try
{
    if (Lines_Array[i + 6].Substring(p, 7).Trim() == "")
        break;
}
catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException) { break; }
```

Example #2:
I need to find out how many "Groze" lines exists in each page.
I need to count until I see the line showed with arrow. But it throws exception.
Screenshot:[image: Sample data for counting]

```
try
{
    while (Lines_Array[i + k].Substring(2, 5).Trim() == "Groze")
    {
        bedensay++;
        k++;
    }
}
catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException) { }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question seem a bit unclear, what is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: As mentioned the Q is unclear. If you just want to avoid ArgumentOutOfRangeException just add a check for Lines_Array length before getting the desired Substring

Comment: Are you familiar with the `for` and/or `foreach` construct? It seems a better fit than a `while`. What is it that you are trying to do exactly?

Comment: I am familiar with those loops but the range varies. This is where I'm trying to find out how many lines of stuff exists.

Comment: do you mean that the range of the `Lines_Array` varies? that seems odd. It might help to provide a bigger example. Perhaps even try to explain the [X instead of the Y](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147063).

Comment: Not Lines_Array but the part I need inside varies. I will provide some sample data regarding X instead of the Y.

Comment: [I wrote a short example of what I think you might be after.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/a7uCny). Does this assist you? Do you need the index of the line after the "Groze"lines?

Comment: The reason I chose `while` is not to scan all array. It is a very big array which is scanned from file and _[there are multiple places in one array. I need them in one pass](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IkAQWG)_ While I'm moving downwards I need result for each part. (4/1 for your example, 4/4/1 for mine)

Comment: That helps a lot (according to me). I think you should add these details to your question and explain what you are trying to do - to me, none of the current answers are targeting your specific issue. I don't know if it is possible but you might even consider closing this one and just start over? But yeah, it's up to you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the framework to throw an exception, just check the string's length before processing it:

```
var line = Lines_Array[i + 6];
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
{
    // Handle empty or null string.

}
else
{
   // Handle non-empty string...
}
```

Comment: Given the original question, I assumed the ArgumentOutOfRangeException was being caused by the SubString()-method.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use exception to control your program flow. Instead avoid them in the first place. Also note that it is a better programming style to execute one statement in one line, and not connecting them - this will improve readability and it is easier to debug if you step through the code.

Example:

```
int index = i + k;
if (index >= Lines_Array.Length)
{
    break;
}
else
{
    var line = Lines_Array[index];
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
    {
        // break; or whatever you need to ...
    }
    else
    {
        // if (line.Substring ... ) and so on
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a check to see if Lines_Array length is 0. Modify your code like this:

```
try
{
    if(Lines_Array.Length != 0)
    {
        while (Lines_Array[i + k].Substring(2, 5).Trim() == "Groze")
        {
            if(Lines_Array.Length <= (i + k))
            {
                bedensay++;
                k++;
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException) { }
```